# How can i use a rest operator method, with an object

Tags: javascript

I'm using a storage system that i can not change, and the data im processing can change properties.

I would like to call the addRow method using the person object without specifying the properties.

Example:

```js
//This is a storage system that i cant change
let storageSystem = {
  data: [],
  columns: [],
  addColumn: function(columnName) {
    this.columns.push(columnName);
  },
  addRow: function(...row) {
    let record = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
      record[this.columns[i]] = row[i];
    }
    this.data.push(record);
  },
  print: function() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
};

//Data that can change completely
let person = {
  Firstname: "Peter",
  Lastname: "Mcdonnel",
  Age: 22
};

//Frome here i can make changes!
storageSystem.addColumn("Firstname");
storageSystem.addColumn("Lastname");
storageSystem.addColumn("Age");

storageSystem.addRow("Peter", "Mcdonnel", 22);
storageSystem.addRow("Jan", "Jansen", 23);

console.log("This should work:");

storageSystem.print();

console.log("I would like this to work aswell:");

//Something i would like to do
storageSystem.addRow(person);

storageSystem.print();

//What i cant do, because the data can change
storageSystem.addRow(person.Firstname, person.Lastname, person.Age);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the rest operator on the array of values:

```
storageSystem.addRow(...Object.values(person));
```

Example:

```js
//This is a storage system that i cant change
const storageSystem = {
  data: [],
  columns: [],
  addColumn: function(columnName) {
    this.columns.push(columnName);
  },
  addRow: function(...row) {
    let record = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
      record[this.columns[i]] = row[i];
    }
    this.data.push(record);
  },
  print: function() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
};

//Data that can change completely
const person = {
  Firstname: "Peter",
  Lastname: "Mcdonnel",
  Age: 22
};

//Frome here i can make changes!
storageSystem.addColumn("Firstname");
storageSystem.addColumn("Lastname");
storageSystem.addColumn("Age");

storageSystem.addRow("Peter", "Mcdonnel", 22);
storageSystem.addRow("Jan", "Jansen", 23);

console.log("This should work:");

storageSystem.print();

console.log("I would like this to work aswell:");

storageSystem.addRow(...Object.values(person));

storageSystem.print();
```

or make `person` an array:

```
const person = ["Peter", "Mcdonnel", 22];
```

Example:

```js
//This is a storage system that i cant change
const storageSystem = {
  data: [],
  columns: [],
  addColumn: function(columnName) {
    this.columns.push(columnName);
  },
  addRow: function(...row) {
    let record = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
      record[this.columns[i]] = row[i];
    }
    this.data.push(record);
  },
  print: function() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
};

//Data that can change completely
const person = ["Peter", "Mcdonnel", 22];

//Frome here i can make changes!
storageSystem.addColumn("Firstname");
storageSystem.addColumn("Lastname");
storageSystem.addColumn("Age");

storageSystem.addRow("Peter", "Mcdonnel", 22);
storageSystem.addRow("Jan", "Jansen", 23);

console.log("This should work:");

storageSystem.print();

console.log("I would like this to work aswell:");

storageSystem.addRow(...person);

storageSystem.print();
```